# Cannondale H400 1993 derailleurs

Tags: derailleur

I would need to replace my derailleurs and I would like to upgrade both front and back.  Front is triple 30, 40, 50 and rear is 13 throught 30.  Both are Shimano Altus A10  with Rapidfire Plus shifters.  What would you recommend?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "upgrade"? Do You want more gears, better gear ratios, better shifting.. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Arthur. We recommend new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're asking [ask] will be helpful also.